# 'Matrices not aligned' in one dot-product example, but works fine in a different example

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do a dot-product between a simple pandas dataframe and a multi-index pandas dataframe.    [I made a toy example to determine the right manipulation, which works fine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412005/vectorized-solution-to-applying-dot-product-to-members-of-a-multindex-pandas-dat/59412179?noredirect=1#comment105012660_59412179)    However, when I do the same manipulation to my real data,  it complains, "ValueError: Matrices not aligned."

The thing is, I cannot see the what the difference between the Toy and Real dataframes are.  The `.shape` and `.index` seem to be identical.  The `dtypes` are different, but i cannot see how that makes a difference.

Does anyone see what the problem is, or what other difference  I'm not checking for?

.

Shapes look the same...

[image]

.

The dtypes are *mostly* the same...

[image]

Also the indices look same.

[image]

But the `.dot` operation works on the toy, fails in the real:

[image]

Generating the toy-example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
yield_data = {"red_delicious":[0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.45, 0.05],
"macintosh":[0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.61, 0.3, 0.05],
'fuji':[0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.35, 0.35],
'config':["a"]*3+['b']*3,
'product':['juice', 'candy', 'pulp']*2}

toy_yield = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(yield_data, ).set_index(['config', 'product'])

index=pd.date_range(start="20191201", end="20191210", freq="d")
price_data = {"juice":(np.random.randint(6000,7000,size=(len(index)))/100),
             'candy': (np.random.randint(6000,7000,size=(len(index)))/100),
             'pulp':(np.random.randint(6000,7000,size=(len(index)))/100),
             }
toy_price = pd.DataFrame(data=price_data, index=pd.date_range(start="20191201", end="20191210", freq="d") )

toy_price.dot(toy_yield.unstack('config'))
```

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images.

Comment: I linked to the code i used to generate the toy example.  I am showing all the measurements that seem to say my working dataframe is identical to the toy dataframe.

Comment: @user3556757, it's best if people can see and select code (if they want to copy) from the question, without having to follow links. Therefore, please share code, not images.

Comment: Please share the code of the variant, which doesn't work. Not the one that works (I think the one you call "the real")

Comment: Also - I was wondering- on this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycmSt.png what's "crude" and "Security"? It doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops... wasted mine and everyone elses' time on this sorry --  the issue was that the name of the columns being dotted with each other were different.  EG: in `toy_price`, the column was `Pie` and in the `toy_yields` frame, the column was called `PIE`.  Pandas couldn't match those. The error message wasn't super useful, but I didn't realize Pandas was smart enough to try that in the first place -- had assumed the `dot()` operation was applied by position of the columns.